# How to analyze deeply every single step of a windows executable/installer

Tags: executable

Say for example I'm searching for a malware that writes data, or sends data about my OS to external sources, or writes hidden files or registry entries.

Is there a particular tool that tells me EVERYTHING an installer/executable does? This is regarding the Windows platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the best tool for you might be [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). It can log all file-system writes, network events, and registry activity:

[image: Process Monitor]

If you need to examine the details of the network traffic, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) will let you capture and see all network communications:

[image: Wireshark]

These two tools should satisfy your ask for "a particular tool that tells me EVERYTHING an installer/executable does?". If, on the other hand, you need to see everything that an installer/executable *could do*, then you'd need to use a disassembler like [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) to examine all possible code paths, but note that this is much more time-consuming and challenging than using the other two tools described above.

Comment: You should probably add [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) to the list.

Comment: @tmr232: API Monitor is a fantastic tool, but the signal-to-noise ratio can be rather low relative to the output of Process Monitor. As such, I'd suggest that BlueStarry try Process Monitor first as it sounds like that will meet his or her needs.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use a tool called RegShot for monitoring changes in the registry. You would take a snapshot of the registry, and then run the suspicious program, any changes will be highlighted by RegShot in the next snapshot you take - [RegShot - Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/)